# redirection from a python cgi page to another page without hyperlinks

Tags: python, apache

I have the following problem. I have my script login.py
and two pages, login.html and welcome.html.
When I log in login.html with email-id and password, then login.py would extract exact user information from mysql. Now I'd like start welcome.html page from login.cgi and passing user information through parameters and display it on welcome page.
Can anybody help me, to solve this problem how to write the python cgi ?

what i actually mean is: you have forward action in jsp to do this....
    
is there anything similar in python cgi...??

Comment: @falsetru after a POST request the [recommended](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-63) response is 303, not 302 nor 301. Those are mostly used for documents that have moved or which are accessed trough an alias.

Answer (score 0):

*http* does support redirect as part of the protocol. Those are the 3xx responses.

After a POST request, you will probably reply with [HTTP 303 See other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) to redirect to the correct document after login. You may pass parameters as usual.

```
print "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other"
print "Location: http://example.org/other?user=xyz"
```

---

See [Webpage redirect to the main page with CGI Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122957/webpage-redirect-to-the-main-page-with-cgi-python)

Comment: is there a specified location where  i should add that?

Comment: That should be the first output of your CGI script. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#introduction

Comment: here the page gets redirected after the current page is executed...but what if i want to make redirection based on a particular condition like if true: redirect to login.py else: redirect to error.py...