# Page Redirect in CGI using Python

Tags: python, cgi

I am trying to write a cgi script in python for a simple login page.
I am trying to redirect this page to my home page on submit of username and password.

Can anyone help me to do this without manipulating the HTTP Headers.

### This is the code that i am using::

```
    #!"D:\Python34\python.exe"

    import cgi
    username=""
    password=""

    def htmlTop():
        print("""Content-type:text/html\n\n
                 <!DOCTYPE html>
                 <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                        <title>Login Form</title>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/userStyles.css">
                    </head>
                    </body>""")
    def htmlBody():
        print("""
                <div class = "container">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <form action="" method="get" name="Login_Form" class="form-signin">       
                            <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Welcome Back! Please Sign In</h3>
                              <hr class="colorgraph"><br>

                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus="" />
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>            

                              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit">Login</button>            
                        </form>         
                    </div>
                </div>
                """)
    def checkForm():
        formData=cgi.FieldStorage()
        if formData.getvalue("Submit"):
            username=formData.getvalue("Username")
            password=formData.getvalue("Password")
            print("Your Username is {0} and your password is {1}".format(username,password))
        else:
            htmlBody()
    def htmlTail():
        print("""   
                    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    </body>
                 </html>""")

    #main program
    if __name__=="__main__":
        try:
                htmlTop()
                checkForm()
                htmlTail()
        except:
            print ("This is the exception")
            cgi.print_exception()
```

---

Comment: See [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122957/webpage-redirect-to-the-main-page-with-cgi-python).

Comment: I tried that method @doru. The problem with that method is if i use it to redirect to page B from A thereafter whenever i open page A it goes to page B even if i remove the Status: and Location: from the header.

Comment: Have you seen the second answer to that question?

Comment: Thanks @doru that seemed to work though i didnt expect it be this complicated in python. In php you just have to call the header funtion and in jsp the response.redirect function. Are you sure there is no such function in python?

Answer (score 0):

As they say in [this post](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=2170050):

> This episode highlights a minor drawback with the CGIHTTPServer module
>   - it does not let us issue 302 Redirects. As this is the case we use an alternative method for our redirect. The correct method is outlined
>   in more detail in this [Python Cookbook Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52287/).

So, or you use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.com" />
```

in your header or you code your redirect function as seen in the above examples.