# how to move page to another page in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python web development and not playing with some web frameworks like django in python for now. Now, is there a way like `PHP` (e.g. `header("Location: page.target.php")`) that to move the page to another in python?

Comment: you can add redirect url to the 'Location' header of the request object

Comment: Check out this [SO Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122957/webpage-redirect-to-the-main-page-with-cgi-python)

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.3+

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^one/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/another/')),
)
```

for earlier version it was: 
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^one/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/another/'}),
)
```

Comment: yeah this is a good point, but is there any way that i could move the page from the other one without the sense of django framework?

Comment: Maybe you can use requests to redirect then like requests.head() or requests.headers()